# PayPal prefil Credit Card detaills

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

So Im trying to prefil the PayPal Credit Card with infos. Therefore I added a payer to my JSON:

```
    "amount": {
      "currency_code": "EUR",
      "value": "100",
      "breakdown": {
        "item_total": {"currency_code": "EUR", "value": "100"}
      }
    },
    "items": [
      {
        "name": "First Product Name",
        "description": "Optional descriptive text..",
        "unit_amount": {"currency_code": "EUR", "value": "50"},
        "quantity": "1"
      },
      {
        "name": "Second Product Name",
        "description": "Optional descriptive text..",
        "unit_amount": {"currency_code": "EUR", "value": "50"},
        "quantity": "1"
      },
    ],
    "payer": {
      "name": {
        "given_name": 'PayPal',
        "surname": 'Customer',
      },
      "address": {
        "address_line_1": '123 ABC Street',
        "address_line_2": 'Apt 2',
        "admin_area_2": 'San Jose',
        "admin_area_1": 'CA',
        "postal_code": '95121',
        "country_code": 'US',
      },
    },
    "invoice_id": "invoice_number_2388",
```

[image: Here]

The Problem is that even though I added the payer the Infos arent prefiled in the credit card. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `payer` object is deprecated. For PayPal, there is `payment_source.paypal`.  For sofort, `payment_source.sofort` object

But the main issue seems to be that you're putting this information inside the `purchase_units` array. It doesn't belong there.

There is a complete guide for integrating sofort in particular here: https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/apm/sofort/

Comment: what should I do when I not only want to accept Sofort but also credit card and so on? May I add multiple payment sources? I don’t know if I’m stupid but what would be an example

Comment: Or is the only thing that I need to fix it putting the payer outside the purchase units?

Comment: When a JS SDK button is clicked, the first parameter to createOrder (usually named `data`) will have a `paymentSource` value